# How do I get a particular Contacts LoggedCalls using the REST API?

Tags: soql, rest-api, api

Salesforce Newbie here. 
I need to get a particular contacts logged calls using the REST API. 
I realized that Calls are under in the Tasks Object with the Property TaskSubtype 
So when I hit `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com//services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Contact/{ContactId}/Tasks`
I get a full list of that contacts Tasks. How do I filter to only get the LoggedCalls from the Tasks and not the other Tasks? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like what you're asking to do is possible with the `SObject` rest resource.

Your options here are to perform the filtering on your side (i.e. use what you currently have to grab all the records, then iterate over the results and filter out the ones you don't want yourself), or to use [the `Query` resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) and supply an appropriate query.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I ended up using the Query resource. Had to write a query combining the contact and the Tasks. That ended up working.

Comment: @Sumaer, if Derek F answered your question don't forget to accept his answer

Answer (score 0):

**This is no longer true** (***at least as of v52*) - you can retrieve related Tasks using syntax like :

e.g. Getting all tasks associated with a contact

```
https://<<your salesforce path>>/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Contact/<<id>>/Tasks?fields=id,description
```

would return

```
{
   "totalSize":1,
   "done":true,
   "records":[
      {
         "attributes":{
            "type":"Task",
            "url":"/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Task/<<task id>>"
         },
         "Id":"<<value>>",
         "Description":"Test"
      }
   ]
}
```